# Having trouble with Nested if-eilf-else statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

I am experiencing an issue with nested if statements in Python running on repl.it and would like help determine what I am doing wrong or if there is a great way to rework the entire section.

**Background and Current Goal:**
I am attempting to make a generic settings module that will work with various different programs.  My goal for the problem block is to be able to detect when a variable is set to a specific string (by a string splitter) to identify the command, and then check the arguments (another variable).  Finally, whatever the command does would be executed.

**Issue**
Python/repl.it will not accept my nested if statements.

**The problem block:**

```
elif(Command=="debug"):
    print("Not Fully Implemented")
    if(Args=='-E'):
      DebugMode =="Enabled"
    elif(Args=="D-"):
      DebugMode == "False"
    elif(Args=="-query"):
      print(str(DebugMode)
    else:
      print("Argument Error.  For a valid list of commands, type     'help'")
```

**The Error message**
(Ignore Color)

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
  File "main.py", line 68
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**The full program so far:**

#SettingsCommandLineUitily
    #Imports
    #Initization
    print("Starting Settings Utitlies...            000%",end="\r")
    from time import sleep
    import sys

```
#Initizatin Countdown
INIT_PERCENT=0
for i in range(97):
  print("Loading Settings Utitlies...            " + str(INIT_PERCENT) +     "%", end="\r")
  INIT_PERCENT += 1
  sleep(0.015)

#Defing Variables
global Args2
global Command
global Args
global DebugMode
DebugMode = "Enabled"
print("Loading Settings Utitlies...        97%", end="\r")

#String Artist
#Splits Input comands into command, args, and args 2 via a space
def StringArtist(CommandIn):
  #Import globals
  global Command
  global Args
  global Args2
  #Parseing
  ParsedCommand = CommandIn.split(" ")
  ParsedCommand.append("Null")
  ParsedCommand.append("Null")
  Command = ParsedCommand[0]
  Args = ParsedCommand[1]
  Args2 = ParsedCommand[2]
print("Loading Settings Utitlies...        98%", end="\r")

#Command Parser
#Interpets Comands and Arguments
def CommandParser(Command, Args, Args2):
  if(Command=="help"):
    print("Displaying Help... ",end="\n")
    print("Command        Args                Function",end="\n")
    print("exit                               Exits the helps         utilty.",end="\n")
    print("help                               Displays This Help     Dialogue",end="\n")
    print("vol            -[0-100/+/-/+10/-10/query]  Sets the volume as     a percenage where zero is off",end="\n")
    print("graphics       -[(B/N/W/query)   Sets the graphics qualitiy     (Best/Normal/Worst)]",end="\n")
    print("_                          Not Implemented",end="\n")
    print("debug          -[E/D/query]      Not Implemented",end="\n")
  elif(Command=="exit"):
    print("Exiting to Program...")
    sys.exit(000)
  elif(Command=="vol"):
    print("Not Implemented")
  elif(Command=="graphics"):
    print("Not Implemented")
  elif(Command=="_"):
    print("Not Implemented")
  elif(Command=="debug"):
    print("Not Fully Implemented")
    if(Args=='-E'):
      DebugMode =="Enabled"
    elif(Args=="D-"):
      DebugMode == "False"
    elif(Args=="-query"):
      print(str(DebugMode)
    else:
      print("Argument Error.  For a valid list of commands, type     'help'")
  elif(Command=="Null"):
    sys.exit("Input may not have a value of 'Null'.  Program Error Code     #201")
  elif(Command==""):
    print("To exit settings and return to your program type exit")
  else:
    print("Command not reconized.  To refer to a refernce list, type     'help'.")
print("Loading Settings Utitlies...        99%", end="\r")

def Main():
  print("\nReturing to Settings Utily...")
  #Import global variables
  global Command
  global Args
  global Args2
  #Main
  print("Enter Command Below or type help for help.")
  #CommandIn=input()
  StringArtist(input())
  CommandParser(Command, Args, Args2)
  #command = "NUll"
  #Args = "Null"
  #Args2= "Null"
print("Loading Settings Utitlies...        COMPLETE", end="\n")
#Debuger
if(DebugMode=="Enabled"):
  while True:
    Main()
```

Comment: FYI, there is no need for parenthesis around the conditions in `if` and `elif` statements in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line before the `else:` is missing a closing parenthesis:

```
print(str(DebugMode)
```